# Dotted distance between acronym and description in acronymlist from glossaries

Tags: glossaries

I'm using `glossaries` package for my acronyms. I used the style listdotted. Unfortunately the distance between the abbreviations and the descriptions in the acronym-list is too big. How can I reduce this distance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it can be solved by setting the length of `\glslistdottedwidth`

```
\setlength{\glslistdottedwidth}{.3\linewidth}
```

Comment: For anyone else who finds this, in case it isn't obvious, for this to take effect you have to use `\printacronyms[style=listdotted]`.